# 12V to 6V Regulator at high current

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, high-current

[image: .]

I am currently working on a project when I need to step down 12V to 6V. This 6V will serve 3 motors. The motors pull 4 amps, 1.5 amps, and 1 amp when they are each at full power.

I am having trouble finding a regulator to step the voltage to 6V while still being able to handle high currents.

In addition, the battery is not attached to an alternator. The battery will slowly lose voltage.

What options do I have? The simpler the better!

Comment: Buy three separate DC/DC converters from amazon/ebay/alibaba/dealextreme/... . They are dirt cheap and especially the ones for lower current should be really easy to find. One for 4A shouldn't be too much of a problem either.

Comment: The problem with a converter is that the battery is not connected to an alternator. The battery is going to slowly lose voltage. Will a 12V to 6V converter continue to work?

Comment: The buck converter is regulated to produce a constant output voltage over some range of input voltages. The discharge of the 12V battery should not cause any problem. However, there is another problem. You will also need to make sure you turn everything off when the battery is fully discharged (at, say, 10V). Otherwise you will probably end up ruining the battery.

Comment: Since you haven't specified the type of 12 battery you're using, I assume it's a standard lead-acid battery.  If you discharge it more than 20% repeatedly, you will noticeably reduce its useful lifetime. If you discharge 80% you'll cut the lifetime by 2/3 or more. http://pvcdrom.pveducation.org/BATTERY/charlead.htm and at 80% discharge you'll still be getting 11.5 volts. http://mbharris.co.uk/12-volt-sound-system-battery-calculator/

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly consider this (below) as a design: -

[image]

The supply above produces a 5v output but by tweaking the ration of R1 to R2 you can produce 6V.

There are plenty of options for building your own. See [this](http://www.linear.com/parametric/External_Power_Switch_Buck_Controllers#!1646_Buck!1032_<=10!1033_>=12!1105_<=6!1034_>=6!1107_8:27!vinmin_10!vinmax_12!vout_6!iout_8!vout2_!iout2_!vout3_!iout3_) link.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to step down voltage. The simplest probably being with a PWM signal. There are IC's that can handle that for you. There is also a buck converter but that cicuit is more complex.

In a cicuit I used a MOSFET and a PWM signal from a micro control. You could even use an 555 timer! The buck convert will probably be the most effective for you seeing how you need larger amounts of current.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Can you elaborate on the buck converter? Or post some links? I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: In additon, this battery will not be connected to an alternator. So the voltage will slowly drop. Will this hinder the buck converter?

Comment: Here is a link to Wikipedia, look under theory of operation to basically see what it does. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter . The inductor is what allows for high current.

Comment: The battery is going to slowly lose voltage. Will a 12V to 6V converter continue to work?

Comment: A buck converter will keep operating (provided the source can provide the ever increasing current) as long as the maximum duty cycle (Vout/Vin) is not violated, although some converters have a requirement for lower duty cycles at start-up.