# Need ideas for stepping down voltage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I need to reliably step down voltage from my 12V adaptor to 6V. I want to be able to get 3-4 Amps from this 6V output. I was until now using a [buck convertor module](https://robu.in/product/lm2596s-dc-dc-buck-converter-power-supply/?gclid=CjwKCAjwkNOpBhBEEiwAb3MvvZtSmiapwD54xps7pw3Xc-ldneA_QLpNNP5CYmQQNcIM_76EgG0PAhoC0tAQAvD_BwE) but even though it advertises 2A capacity I do not think it is able to give that much. I need some options. I don't mind building my own step down module, but I'd be happy if there is some off the market options available.

One thing which came to my mind was to use a voltage divider. Is a voltage divider a good idea for this?

Comment: A voltage divider is the worst idea for this, for reasons you can find by looking at other people who have asked about voltage dividers as power supplies on here.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535871/ldo-and-buck-converter will give insight into the matter. || A voltage divider is a **horrible** choice.

Comment: What does a professional regulated power supply use?

Comment: Are you interested only in a switching solution, or is a linear regulator a possibility?  Also, what is the load the 6 V output will be driving?

Comment: Actually, by coincidence, there's [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198927/12v-to-6v-regulator-at-high-current?rq=1) on here from several years ago that appears to be asking the same thing: 12 to 6 volts at high current (higher than yours, but that doesn't matter).

Comment: @AnalogKid I need to drive 4-5 solenoid valves drinking up 200-300mA individually, but I might need to drive more in future

Comment: @Hearth thanks, I'll go through it

Comment: I don't think a voltage divider will be suitable for your purpose. Rather use a good quality buck converter from a dependable manufacturer. If 2A output current is sufficient for you, you can consider SparkFun Buck-Boost Converter. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15208

Comment: substitute 12 V valves

Comment: When the solenoids are on, are they on continuously or pulsed?

Comment: @AnalogKid continuously, for like a few seconds

Comment: "Use a buck converter" is in general the right answer. If you don't trust you have, then get a better one from a reputable supplier (which neither Amazon nor ebay are).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to buy rather than build, ebay is awash with buck converters rated for 5 A or more, for less than $10.00.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/334975771550?hash=item4dfe1ca39e:g:LkQAAOSwVstkQ78V&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAAwN3nsqaGIxj3zPIoM2foOobXanzGgtXM9yLeXdv6BBHEpM%2BU4Xr1xi8A%2Bs%2Bgz%2BxaYsl0keoDf6bJ3MSxWUDMqh5LGtgwicUNv6gZ4SkzBIqNqlflpI60ea8CdRPNzAmGw372xapjpkLF2KUpAWGpTOKx9DTmyu2GLbsckmK9%2Fnww24e8k73Azg6Qx4Kk5o5Yh319xDgPCkymj547nEuU6Xbv65QNuqRhK50wBU5hw4r302xQ2m%2Fk8itThcrYL%2BxJiQ%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5yElorrYg

https://www.ebay.com/itm/196012321112?hash=item2da33ea958:g:atsAAOSw0MNi0lSY&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4OoF0i%2FZNzKmO7Y4I0TFT0e9nvbQPR15eqyujbdDW1W5PnEpVFpubtOV9rjpsQGvXHw2duJLkfO5hjszovdFTFYFRajWLc7bPplhDthdWpUyPj%2F6RGX%2Fd8zU4k%2BlFOjxoCm%2FOz1QL%2Fq7FeGmARj1KaNThuz%2F%2FPVqJJPGPFvInBt%2FIcyi9rIrveqZ0C1f0745hzdXpcH4hsOUU%2FYLhoTk4a9BMohoX12C6ljb12U4SWipF9hbnfeIVKdCj9bG2vObnVtEc1FLkr0vW2SZs9twguFvAKBVRSDAPp%2FCQ9VU6pf2%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR56ElorrYg

Some modules have die-cast heatsinks built in.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/334410996889?var=&hash=item4ddc72dc99&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA8GX6Wdnzec3t8hcSfWnZV8%252B3Q7LqXlXAYiXsC8z%252Bz2Wi0jKiDAq1C3nFpSqV%252B9%252FmFNvfiV3LSaB8C%252FmQcnmATTYws6gWCpSMdrsvOil%252FJwOWKi7ItEzq8NYTaLvHIzNvhbUfZTMLND%252FempG5BAmQ00D%252B6rx7Bi0C75ShhRGBvbrMWCd%252BvccuTnC4ZC6O7%252BS7HuLP3sprceG%252FIJP%252BEGPmcU3oLFGHLxgyz68GOR7vZ7QOeNgYMVXg8LReH%252FWarvdHQYvZHr0wQFz3x7DtXydl7nlBWNxedYU8vTbuDIUVEczTXboiQLLolKJwdXyWsjSPGg%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK

Comment: You're surely aware that 'shopping questions' are off-topic. As such, why would you post a 'shopping answer'?